# add letter before each numerical value in the data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, substitution

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,NA,1),
                 b=c(2,3,3,NA,6),
                 c=c(1,NA,1,1,1),
                 d=c(2,2,3,1,1),
                 e=c(1,2,1,2,1))
head(df)
  a  b  c d e
1  1  2  1 2 1
2  1  3 NA 2 2
3  2  3  1 3 1
4 NA NA  1 1 2
5  1  6  1 1 1
```

I would like to add character "Q" to each value, but NA. For example, the desired output will look like that:

```
    a    b    c  d  e
1   Q1   Q2   Q1 Q2 Q1
2   Q1   Q3 <NA> Q2 Q2
3   Q2   Q3   Q1 Q3 Q1
4 <NA> <NA>   Q1 Q1 Q2
5   Q1   Q6   Q1 Q1 Q1
```

I was trying the following line of code: `df[] <- sub("^", "Q", df[])`, but it does not produce the desired output.

Thank you for your help!
Olha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ifelse` with `paste` after looping over the columns with `lapply`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(!is.na(x), paste0("Q", x), x))
```

-output

```
df
#     a    b    c  d  e
#1   Q1   Q2   Q1 Q2 Q1
#2   Q1   Q3 <NA> Q2 Q2
#3   Q2   Q3   Q1 Q3 Q1
#4 <NA> <NA>   Q1 Q1 Q2
#5   Q1   Q6   Q1 Q1 Q1
```

---

Or it can be also done with a logical index on both sides of the assignment

```
df[!is.na(df)] <-  paste0("Q", df[!is.na(df)])
```

NOTE:

`sub` needs a `vector` as input for 'x' and not a data.frame.  Here, it is more easier to use `paste` instead of `sub`

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), 
       ~ case_when(!is.na(.) ~ str_c('Q', .), TRUE ~ NA_character_)))
```